# Como criar projeto web.api MVC 4 ao invés de MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Estou com um problema na hora de criar o meu projeto no VS 2015, sempre que crio a aplicação web.api ela cria com a versão do MVC 5, mas preciso que seja MVC 4 por causa da hospedagem. 
Fazer downgrade de versão não dá certo, o VS não faz o downgrade de todas as referências e gera muito conflito.

Comment: Não sei responder de cabeça, mas já te adianto que você vai ter que adicionar estes recursos à IDE e fazer algumas configurações manuais.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro instalar o Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web em uma maquina virtual (no Azure ou AWS - uma conta trial deve ser suficiente), criar o projeto ASP.NET MVC 4 lá, salvar (num repositorio Git ou Svn, de preferencia) e abrir na sua máquina com o VS 2015 com Update 1 (a partir desta versão parece suportar o ASP.NET MVC 4, embora não seja possivel criar).